# rest controller to return records in kafka via spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-web

For my demo application, I have to create a rest controller to return the message in the kafka queue. I have read the spring-kafka reference guide and implemented the consumer configuration and created beans as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfiguration {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        // allows a pool of processes to divide the work of consuming and processing records
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "trx");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Transaction> transactionConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfigs(),new StringDeserializer(),new JsonDeserializer<>(Transaction.class)
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Transaction>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Transaction> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(transactionConsumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer() {
        return new Consumer();
    }

}
```

and another class consumer like below

```
public class Consumer {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}")
    public void receive(Transaction transaction) {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

How can I now implement the logic to retrieve transaction from the consumer on each get hit on the controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the `@KafkaListener` produces independent long-lived process to stream records from Kafka to the callback. Since you are talking about the REST GET event, you don't have choice unless obtain the `KafkaConsumer` from the `ConsumerFactory` and call its `poll()` manually from the controller method.

Comment: Thanks Artem for your reply, Can you please point me to some guide or documentation for same.

Comment: Maybe this: http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the code and it seems that it doesn't use spring-kafka and directly using the kafka api. Am i right?

Comment: ??? That’s what I meant with my answer. Spring Kafka doesn’t provide poll API. You have to use `KafkaConsumet` directly. Although you get a gain from the Spring Kafka `ConsumerFactory` with its auto-configuration for the properties

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help.